# Angular 2 make array/object by recieved json http get

Tags: angular, typescript

I recieving a json to an

```
items:any = [];

items[0]['name']
items[0]['adres']
items[0]['lat']
items[0]['lng']
```

In this i have 4 keys and need only 2, lat and lng.

How can i make an markers array like this dynamic from the items in my app.component.ts?

```
markers = [
    {
        lat: 51.673858,
        lng: 7.815982
    },
    {
        lat: 51.373858,
        lng: 7.215982
    },
    {
        lat: 51.723858,
        lng: 7.895982
    }
]
```

Comment: `Loop` is one of the solutions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var n = 0;
var markers = items.map(item => {
    lat: item['lat'],
    lng: item['lng'],
    label: String.fromCharCode(65 + n++)
});
```

Btw, this is not related to Angular2 but TypeScript instead.

Comment: Ahah, almost there, how can i append an label: value , so the value has to be A, B , C , etc

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do.

Comment: google maps needs a "label", so by the first key i need an A and by the second B etc. var markers = items.map(item => {
    lat: item['lat'],
    lng: item['lng'],
    label: dynamic A,B,C, etc so by every row
})

Comment: @Bas You can use `String.fromCharCode()`.